# What's "protocol relative" // called (i.e. instead of http:// or https://)?

Tags: terminology, rfc

You can write `//google.com` instead of `http://google.com` and `https://google.com` where `//` is relative to your current protocol. But what's the term for `//`?

Comment: Forward slash forward slash ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hierarchical partition?  A segment separator? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Generic_syntax

Comment: I guess I'm more looking for the name of the method of doing the relative linking, rather than what the syntax for this portion of the URI would be called. It sounds a bit awkward to say it's a separator/partition when it's not actually separating anything in this instance.